# transclude: 'element' along with templateUrl, is it feasible?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that puts the element on an isolated scope and apply a controller to it, so it can deal with state, AJAX calls and validation.

```html
<div login> 
  <div class="dropdown" ng-click="loginctrl.showForm()">
    Login <span class="caret"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The current transcluded element becomes:

```html
<!-- login -->
<div class="login">
  <div class="dropdown" ng-click="loginctrl.showForm()">
    Login <span class="caret"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I have a `templateUrl` that I want to append along with the contents of the directive, so I'm using `transclude: 'element'` to fine grain the transclusion:

```js
angular
.module('Login.module', [])
.controller('LoginCtrl', function(){
  this.login = function(){
     // do ajax calls for login
  };

  this.logout = function(){ 
     // do ajax calls for logout
  };

  this.facebook = function(){  
    // do ajax calls for facebook login
  };

  this.showForm = function(){
     // shows the template form
  };

  this.user = {}; // user model
})
.directive('login', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: 'element',
    controllerAs: 'loginctrl',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    replace: false,
    templateUrl: '/templates/login',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
      transclude(scope, function(clone){
        clone.wrap('<div class="login"></div>');
        element.after(clone); // "element" is the <!-- login --> HTML comment
        // "clone" is the transcluded contents of the div, that is the login with ng-click, etc
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The `templateUrl` (that is a login / register form) is downloaded through AJAX (see it in dev tools), but it can't be used inside the link function nor the transclude. Am I missing something? Couldn't find any help in this regard and I've been looking for a few days now.

Dumbed down version of the problem http://plnkr.co/edit/NzS7cAej17RnQxARlli3?p=preview

Comment: What is the exact end result you're trying to accomplish including where the elements in the template should end up? It's not entirely clear to me. Also, if you want that `clone.wrap(...)` to have an effect you have to do the `element.after(clone)` first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT after comments:

I've updated [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bILu5R5nB9uzYUkF9NDa?p=preview) with the following, which I think does what you want. I've included some additional explanation of what's going on.

```
.directive('login', function() {
  var useElementTransclusion = true;
  var replace = true;
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: useElementTransclusion ? 'element' : true,
    controllerAs: 'loginctrl',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    replace: useElementTransclusion ? true : replace,
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      // If transclude is 'element', then the element argument is
      // the HTML comment which is put in the place of the entire
      // element on which the directive was applied.
      // If transclude is true, then the element argument depends
      // on the value of replace. If replace is true then element 
      // is the content of the template. If replace is false then
      // element is the element on which the directive was applied.
      transclude(scope, function(clone) {
        // If transclude is 'element' then clone is an array
        // containing the single element on which the directive
        // was applied.
        // If transclude is true then clone is an array containng
        // the children of the element on which the directive was
        // applied.
        element.wrap('<div class="login"></div>');
        element.after(clone);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

If you use `transclude; 'element'` then you have to use `replace: true`, for somewhat of an explanation [see this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3368). If you use `transclude: true` the you can use whatever value you want for `replace` depending on the end result you want with respect to the original HTML node on which the directive was applied (whether it will still exist or not).

---

The following is the original answer, left here for no particular reason...

Not entirely sure if this leads to the exact result you're expecting, but ...

```
.directive('login', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: 'element',
    controllerAs: 'loginctrl',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '/templates/login',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      transclude(scope, function(clone) {
        element.after(clone);
        clone.wrap('<div class="login"></div>');
      });
    }
  };
})
```

As seen in [this fork of your plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bILu5R5nB9uzYUkF9NDa?p=preview).

The changes are:

- Change replace to 'true'
- Add the clone to the DOM before wrapping so that the wrapping is added to the DOM also.

Comment: the `<div class="login">` needs to wrap the entire element (template + transcluded element). and why it needs `replace: true`?

Comment: thanks, it works. angular can be a blackbox sometimes

Comment: this is such an amazing answer. helped me out a lot. thanks for your help @imaginaryboy